# CodeIgniter configuration for multi domain home

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing, app-config

I've built a CI App and was just recently informed that it will have to be multi homed.  That is, it will be on a server that has 2 NICs.  One for the `www` and the other for an internal address.

I'm not too sure what value I'm supposed to use in my config file's `base_url`.  Technically, users of the site should be able to access it by going to either:

`www.widgets.com` - public address

or

`http://ourserver.widgets.net` - internal address

How do I configure my CI App to allow for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Mada, which part is unclear?  I'm happy to try to clarify it! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

CodeIgniter will figure out the `base_url` by itself.

Answer (score 3):

Modify the configuration of `base_url` in `./application/config/config.php` to the following

```
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Base Site URL
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
  | WITH a trailing slash:
  |
  | http://example.com/
  |
  | If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
  | path to your installation.
  |
 */
$config['base_url'] = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';;
```

It accept any domains either `widgets.com` or `ourserver.widgets.net` with `http` and `https` protocols. Thanks!!

Comment: madan, can you tell me what the difference is between your solution and the option to leave it base_url blank?

Comment: There are limits to this solution, for instance: what happens when the protocol changes from `http`to `https`? Best to have CI do the heavy lifting in this case, I think...

Comment: @MadanSapkota Cool, but if CI can do it all by itself, why bother reinventing the wheel?